# Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged(in Excel) not working in all web browsers

Tags: office-addins, office-js

[image: Code sample]

I am trying to add  `DocumentSelectionChanged` event handle in Excel online document (tested in all browsers). Creating this event is failing from last 15 days.

Please help me here

**P.S: Same event working fine in Excel 2013 desktop environment**

```
 Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged, function(eventArgs) {
     console.log(eventArgs);
 }, function(asyncResult) {
     console.log(asyncResult);
 });
```

> OSF.DDA.AsyncResult {value: undefined, status: "failed", error: OSF.DDA.Error}error: OSF.DDA.Errorcode: 5001message: "An internal error has occurred."name: "Internal Error"**proto**: OSF.DDA.Errorconstructor: (n,t,i)**proto**: Objectstatus: "failed"value: undefined__proto__: OSF.DDA.AsyncResultconstructor: (n,t)**proto**: Object

Here is link to test at http://aka.ms/R2yi5b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your patience. I am glad to tell you that this fix has been deployed and it is working on all web browsers now. Thanks again for submitting your feedback.

Cheers,
Sky

Answer (score 1):

**Update (Nov 6th 2015, afternoon):**

On further investigation, it appears that there **is** a known bug in Excel Online that is causing this issue. The regression was noticed and already fixed a couple of weeks ago, however the fix has not made it to all endpoints yet (which explains why some folks were seeing it, while others, myself included, were not). We are looking at ways in which we can expedite the patch rollout.

We'll keep this thread updated as the fix makes its way through the system.

---

**Original answer (Nov 6th 2015, morning):**

I just tried it, and am **not** seeing the failure.

One thing I have noticed, though, is that the code on the shared link has a bug. The syntax of addHandlerAsync is that it accepts first the event type, then a handler, and then a callback function to report whether the event-handling succeeded or not. In the case of the shared project, it looked like it was instead assumed that the second argument is the success handler, and the second one was a failure handler(?).  Instead, for that last argument, you should check `asyncStatus.status` to check the success state.

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    // The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded
    Office.initialize = function(reason) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            app.initialize();
            addDocumentHandler();
        });
    };

    function addDocumentHandler() {
        Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync(
            Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged,
            eventHandler,
            function(asyncResult) {
                if (asyncResult.status == "succeeded") {
                    app.showNotification("Success", "Error handler was added");
                } else {
                    app.showNotification("Error setting event: ", JSON.stringify(asyncResult));
                }
            }
        );

        function eventHandler(eventArgs) {
            Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text, function(asyncResult) {
                if (asyncResult.status == "succeeded") {
                    app.showNotification("Value of selection: ", asyncResult.value);
                } else {
                    app.showNotification("Error", "Cannot read selection value");
                }
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

I tried using the [Office API Tutorial App](https://store.office.com/api-tutorial-for-office-WA104077907.aspx) as well, the "SelectionChanged" tutorial.  And there too everything works correctly.  Could you try that?

[image]

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT

Comment: Any update. I am from India, still see this issue. is there a work around?

Comment: I got it tested in US as well. It is failing

Comment: I tested today. Please see the below screenshot for same.http://i.stack.imgur.com/hfJSA.png

Comment: We've taken steps to expedite the fix.  I don't have an ETA yet for when the patch will make it to all farms, but will update this thread as soon as I have more info.

Comment: Hi Michael, We are still facing issue. Any update on this ?

Comment: Hi [Michael Zlatkovsky](http://stackoverflow.com/users/678505/michael-zlatkovsky), We are still facing issue. How many days it will take to expedite fix to all end points though you have fix ready.