# Missing method in JavaScript API for Excel: copy a sheet

Tags: excel, office-addins, office365-apps, office-js

Since there is no way to cancel the changes made by an add-in, we need to provide users with backup options.

The current version of JavaScript API for Excel doesn't have a method for copying a sheet with its data and formatting.

Does anyone know of any workarounds or plans for adding such method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are indeed currently no way easy way of duplicating a worksheet and so feel free to request it on the [Office Extensibility Platform's UserVoice](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/83526-office-js). While such an API may be coming in the future, you could in the meantime add a new worksheet using [`worksheetCollection.add()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt598671.aspx#addname_string), grab a worksheet's used range using the [`worksheet.getUsedRange()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt598672.aspx#getusedrange) method and copy its values to another sheet.

Your code would then look something like this :

```js
function duplicateSheet(worksheetName) {
    Excel.run(function(ctx) {
        var worksheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(worksheetName);
        var range = worksheet.getUsedRange();
        range.load("values", "address");

        var newWorksheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.add(worksheetName + " - Backup");
        return ctx.sync().then(function() {
            var newAddress = range.address.substring(range.address.indexof("!") + 1);
            newWorksheet.getRange(newAddress).values = range.values;              
        }).then(ctx.sync);
    });
}
```

Let me know how that works out for you.

Gabriel Royer - Developer on the Office Extensibility Team, MSFT

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @GabRoyer, we've already used this solution to backup values and formulas. We've added the suggestion to the UserVoice.

Comment: Could you please let us know when Office Extensibility Team are planning to support the new JavaScript API in Excel online?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the APIs are available in Excel Online starting today (or yesterday) actually! It might take some time to roll out everywhere, but they should be available to you soon.

Comment: It's great to see the new API working, however, the previous version of API (Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync) stopped working today. 

When we try to connect to the Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged event, the result is always "failed" and we get the message "An internal error has occurred."

You can also see this issue in the API Tutorial (Content) sample add-in:

https://store.office.com/api-tutorial-for-office-WA104077907.aspx?assetid=WA104077907

Comment: The following thread tracks the issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542902/office-eventtype-documentselectionchangedin-excel-not-working-in-all-web-brows/33574470#33574470. We should have an update soon that we'll post on this thread.

Comment: Hi @GabRoyer, 
this issue hasn't been updated in a month, do you happen to know approximate time it may take to fix this?

Comment: @RenatTlebaldziyeu Let me follow with the right people about that. This bug has been fixed a long while ago, not sure why it hasn't rolled out yet.